# connect ETIMEDOUT error while doing POST query in Express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing a simple post call. My code is as follows:

```
var express    = require('express');        
var app        = express();                
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        
var router = express.Router();             
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o');
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); 
});enter code here

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

var Bear     = require('./app/models/bears');
router.route('/bears')    
.post(function(req, res) {
    var bear = new Bear();     
    bear.name = req.body.name;  
    bear.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });

});

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

I was previously getting the following error

`failed to connect to [novus.modulusmongo.net:27017]`

which I rectified by updating mongoose but now still i am getting another error as:

```
/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                  ^
```

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.209.84.209:27017

Comment: Is the mongo server running? The service should be running before you could initiate a connection.

Comment: The URL that you have given in the code looks like a remote database. Are you sure you have access to it and it is running? Try running the database locally.

Comment: yes i had started the mongo server beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the below sample

```
var mg= require('mongoose');
var db = mg.connection; 
mg.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o');

db.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('open connection to mongo server.');
});

db.on('connected', function (ref) {
   console.log('Connected connection to mongo server.');
});

db.on('disconnected', function (ref) {
  console.log(ref);
  console.log('disconnected connection.');  
});

db.on('close', function (ref) {
   console.log('close connection.');
});

db.on('error', function (ref) {
  console.log(ref);
    console.log('Error connection.');
});

db.on('reconnected', function () {
  console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});
```

Below is the error i got.

```
 { MongoError: failed to connect to server [novus.modulusmongo.net:27017] on first connect
at Pool.<anonymous> (E:\v2.4.1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:313:35)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (E:\v2.4.1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:260:12)
at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\v2.4.1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:162:49)
at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 name: 'MongoError',
 message: 'failed to connect to server [novus.modulusmongo.net:27017] on first connect' }
```

So i feel essentially its just the connection string or port or username or password is incorrect. try connecting with above code by simply changing the connection string, port , username or password..

Remember 27017 is not the default port always specially on hosted server

try mlab and see if it connects its free for testing and get your connection string here https://mlab.com/ to see if all your code is working perfectly

Hope that helps you